# setting query parameter in azure function v2

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to set a query paramter in azure function v2. the Name query parameter remains null. What am I missing. The url I use in postman is http://localhost:7071/api/ScheduledJob/Frank

```
 [FunctionName("ScheduledJob")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get",
 Route = "{name}")] HttpRequest req,
                ILogger log)
    {
    string name = req.Query["name"];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route definition is incorrect. Base URL defaults to `/api` not `/api/FunctionName`.

Use this -

```cs
Route = "ScheduledJob/{name}"
```

Now your URL becomes

```sh
http://localhost:7071/api/ScheduledJob/{name}
```

instead of

```sh
http://localhost:7071/api/{name}
```

which is what you have right now.

You also don't need to declare `name` as a new variable in your code, use it in the binding instead:

```cs
[FunctionName("HttpTrigger")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post",
            Route = "ScheduledJob/{name}")] HttpRequest req,
            string name,
            ILogger log)
        {

            return new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}");
        }
```

```sh
$ curl http://localhost:7071/api/ScheduledJob/Frank
Hello, Frank
```